# Trouble calling back variables

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, callback

I am having troubles with an exercise in my Visual Basic class.

I need to use a sub procedure can recognize whether or not certain radio buttons are selected and have them add to the cost of the product for sale.
I then need to reference them in the `btnClick` procedure so I can use that to display the cost to the string.

Instructions for reference:

```
Mats-R-Us sells three different types of mats:<br> 
- Standard ($99),<br>
- Deluxe ($129),<br>
- INTERMEDIATE Premium ($179).<br>

All of the mats are available in:<br>
- blue,<br>
- red ($10 extra), <br>
- pink ($15 extra). <br>
```

There is also an extra $25 charge if the customer wants the mat to be foldable.

> Create a Windows Forms application. Use the following names for the
>   project and solution, respectively: Mats Project and Mats Solution.
>   Save the application in the VB2017\Chap06 folder. Create the interface
>   shown in Figure 6-58. Use a function to determine the price of the mat
>   before any additional charges. Use a Sub procedure to calculate the
>   total additional charge (if any).

The code I currently have:
`Option Explicit On`, `Option Strict On`, `Option Infer Off`

[image]

```
Public Class frmMain
    Private Function GetStandard(dblTotal As Double) As Double
        Dim dblPrice As Double

        If radStandard.Checked Then
            dblPrice = 99
        ElseIf radDeluxe.Checked Then
            dblPrice = 129
        ElseIf radPremium.Checked Then
            dblPrice = 179
        End If
        Return dblPrice
        dblPrice = dblTotal
    End Function

    Private Sub AddColorCost(ByRef dblTotal As Double)
        Dim dblPrice As Double
        If radRed.Checked Then
            dblPrice = dblPrice + 10
        ElseIf radPink.Checked Then
            dblPrice = dblPrice + 15
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
        Dim DblTotal As Double
        Call AddColorCost(dblTotal)
        lblPrice.Text = dblTotal.ToString("C2")
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Edit: I have attempted to include the price increases in the subfunction but $0 is the only number that displays when I debug everything.

Comment: Are they all just a bunch of checkboxes for colors/foldable?  Seems strange for an interface choice considering there should only be 1 checked of the "standard" pricing and color (assuming you're only calculating a single price).

Comment: Add more details to your code.  Your question is not clear enough

Comment: @NathanChampion I was given an image to model the interface off of and it does have more than 1 radio button for standard pricing. The interface has 6 buttons including the 2 for the standard cost. It has 1 checkbox to indicate the foldable option.

Comment: @preciousbetine I honestly just need some help with everything. I am able to display the cost for the different mat types but I don't know how to code in the different color costs as well as the foldable option. The issue with adding more details is that I don't know what to add.

Comment: Diane Zak exercise... you also should be confirming if the user wants to exit the application...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Yes, I know that I need to do that still. I wanted to get the sub-functions done and ready before I get to that step.

Comment: Add a screenshot of the form you've designed.

Comment: @preciousbetine I added a screenshot but it ended up at the top of the post and is kinda small. You can still get the general idea from it though. I have to use that design for the form.

Comment: I have added an answer, check below

Comment: I think one of your main problems is scope. A variable declared inside a method (a Sub or Function) can only be seen by code inside that method. You can pass values to other methods as you did with `AddColorCost(dblTotal)`.

Comment: In your first Function you Return a value as you should but you have another line of code after the Return. The running of the program has returned to where it was called from and that last line will not run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's follow the instructions.
Use a function to determine the price of the mat before any additional charges.

```
Private Function BaseCost() As Decimal
        Dim dblPrice As Decimal

        If radStandard.Checked Then
            dblPrice = 99
        ElseIf radDeluxe.Checked Then
            dblPrice = 129
        ElseIf radPremium.Checked Then
            dblPrice = 179
        End If
        Return dblPrice
End Function
```

Use a Sub procedure to calculate the total additional charge (if any).
Since we are using a Sub and not returning a value we will use a Form level (class level) variable so other methods can see it. Another approach would be to pass a parameter ByRef but don't worry about that now.
`AddChanges += 10` is a shortcut way to write `AddChanges = AddChanges + 10`

```
'This variable is Form level (class level) it is not inside a method but it is inside the class.
Private AddCharges As Decimal

Private Sub AdditionalCharges()
        If radRed.Checked Then
            AddCharges += 10
        ElseIf radPink.Checked Then
            AddCharges += 15
        End If
        If chkFoldable.Checked Then
            AddCharges += 25
        End If
End Sub
```

Now add it all up in the calculate button

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        Dim Total As Decimal
    'BaseCost is a Function and returns a value
        Total = BaseCost()
    'AdditionalCharges is a Sub and will change the Form level variable
        AdditionalCharges() 
        Total += AddCharges
        lblPrice.Text = Total.ToString("C2")
        'reset AddCharges so you can make different selections and Calculate again.
        AddCharges = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: @preciousbetine Just more explanation and following the directions to have a Sub procedure showing the difference between a Sub and a Function.